# Javascript Remove Duplicates Ints From Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on a Leet code challenge where I'm trying to remove all duplicates from a sorted ascending array of integers.

So for example [1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5] should return [1,2,3,4,5].

I have solved this one way, but was trying a different way as per the code below, but it seems to always return an empty array [].

Could anyone point me in the direction (of what might be very obvious but I havent seen it) of why this always returns an empty array?

```js
var removeDuplicates = function(nums) {
    
    for(let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        let counter = 0;
        for(let x = i + 1; x < nums.length; x++) {
            // Remove element if above is true
            if(nums[i] == nums[x]) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        nums.splice(i + 1, counter);
    }
    return nums;
};

console.log(removeDuplicates( [1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5] ));
```

Comment: It seems to work fine.

Comment: It is working fine!

Comment: Perhaps the problem is related to leetcode itself expecting you to return a function instead? The code itself is working as intended.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ it still means that it's not *always* returning an empty array. I don't have the time or inclination to 1. reverse engineer the code 2. try inputs to find which fails. [mcve] isn't supposed to be crowd-sourced.

Comment: Thanks all. Yes, I have run this elsewhere and it seems to work fine also. Seems like leetcode might be the issue here! Thanks!

Comment: @VLAZ - And to make things worse, the example that jumped out at me for where it fails isn't a "sorted ascending array" so yeah, the code works. Sigh.

Answer (score 1):

You will get an empty array, because your algorithm is wrong. Your algorithm will works correctly just when the similar numbers are side by side each other. For example:

```js
[1,1,1,2,2,5,5,5,5,5,3,3]
```

Otherwise it doesn't work correctly.

There are lots of algorithm to remove duplicated values from an array. Please have a simple search to find them. But you can easily remove duplicate values in an array in these ways:

```js
function removeDuplicates(numbers) {
    return [...new Set(numbers)];
}
```

Or:

```js
function removeDuplicates(numbers) {
    return numbers.filter((num, index, self) => index === self.indexOf(num));
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks. Yes I agree it will only work with the same numbers side by side. Thats what I am solving. I've written in the post 'sorted ascending array of integers'. I dont expect this to work on an array where integers aren't sorted.